# Insert primary key from one table into another based on user input from a form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I have a form with an `asp:DropDownList` that populates its contents from the `Item_Description` column in the `Item` table.

I would like to allow users to select an item from the drop-down list, and when the form is submitted, insert the `ItemID` value for the selected item into the Orders table using C#/T-SQL.

I could theoretically accomplish this with some lengthy if/else statements, but this seems too simple to require so much code.

I am able to update other tables by assigning `asp:Textbox` values to parameters and inserting them upon submission. I just can't seem to figure out how to pass the `ItemID` to the `Orders` table when a user selects a related item from the list.

P.S. I have already established a connection to my database, protected against SQL injection, etc.

Drop-down list:

ID="ddlItems"

Code for tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Item
(
    ItemID int primary key,
    Item_Description varchar(255)
); 

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderID int primary key,
    Order_Item varchar(255)
);
```

Code-behind method for Submit button click event:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    conn = new SqlConnection("Server=*omitted*");
    comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Orders VALUES @ItemID;", conn);

    comm.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    comm.Parameters["@ItemID"].Value = <<<This is where I need help>>>;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        results.Text = "Error adding data. ";
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the connection
        conn.Close();
        results.Text = "Added data.";
    }
}
```

Drop-down List binding:

```
<asp:DropDOwnList ID="ddlItems" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Item_Description" DataValueField="Item_Description">
<asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
<asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: We can't Use Where Clause with Insert Statement In Sql Server

Comment: show code where you are binding your drop down list and also the schema of table from where you are taking data for drop down list!

Comment: @Dhaval it is easy if you can show your drop down bind code!

Comment: Can I just set the DataValueField="ItemID" to make this work?

Comment: Basically what you Want Bind drop Down or Insert Data ?? I still Not Understand you Question  so Please Explore More so i can Give Code...

Comment: I really don't think I could be more specific. I want to send ItemID to Orders once a user selects an item from ddlItems and clicks the submit button.

Comment: I give You Bind DropDown Code  Please My Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are binding your drop downlist with the `Item` table.

So follow this approach.

1. Query would be (For binding drop downlist data from item table)

   `select * from item`
2. In C#

   `ddlItems.DataSource = "your data table in which you are taking result of above query";
   ddlItems.DataBind();`

(I think you already have done the above steps)

3. Now just add two attribute to your drop down list in source like this.

   ```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItems" runat="server" DataTextField="Item_Description"   DataValueField="ItemID " >
   ```
4. Now you can directly access the id for selected item in drop down from c# code

   `comm.Parameters["@ItemID"].Value=  ddlItems.SelectedItem.Value;`

***Edit***

Now looking at your edited question you just need to change `DataValueField="ItemID"` only :)

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive assistance. I am still having issues with my larger version, but this works with my simple example and, most importantly, directly addressed my main issue instead of focusing on things that were contextually irrelevant.

Comment: welcome :) and if you have any other issue in which we can help, you can just drop comment here or in question.

Comment: I think I got it. I just needed to set comm.Parameters["@ItemID"].Value = ddlItems.SelectedValue after applying your answer. This seems to be returning the value I originally wanted it to.

Comment: Actually both `ddlItems.SelectedItem.Value` and `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` are same :)

Answer (score 0):

As per you Quetion I think You Insert Query Does't Require Where Condition Just Remove the Condition

Bind DropDown Code

```
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        Cmd.CommandText = sqlcmd;
        Cmd.CommandTimeout = this.Timeout;
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = Cmd;
        sda.Fill(ds);


        ddl.DataSource = ds.dt[0];
        ddl.DataTextField = ds.dt[0][COlumnname]
        ddl.DataValueField = ds.dt[0][ColumnName];
        ddl.DataBind();
```

Comment: Wouldn't that cause all ItemID values to be inserted into Orders upon executing Submit_Click()?

Comment: NO it Will Insert only Single Record

Comment: @Dhaval your suggestion is right but it is not the answer.You could have comment on the question

Answer (score 0):

```
I would join the Item and Orders table by ItemID, not Item_Description.

CREATE TABLE Item
(
    ItemID int primary key,
    Item_Description varchar(255)
); 

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderID int primary key,
    ItemID int 
);

I would set a referential constraint on ItemID.  ddlItems should have DataValueField of ItemID and DataTextField of Item_Description.

Assuming ItemID and OrderID are auto-incrementing, you could write:

SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Orders (ItemID) VALUES (@itemID)");
```

This is also assuming only one ItemID could be associated with an Order, otherwise, you would need Item, Order, and OrderItemAsc tables.

Comment: Looks like I may have been on the right track when asking about changing DataValueField.